# Pass & as text in URL?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".commentPost").live('click',function() {
        var expressID = $(this).attr('id');
        var comment = $("#getComment"+expressID).attr('value');

        //If comment contains & then how to pass it in URL??
        $.get('../addons/comment.jsp?comment='+comment+'&expressID='+expressID, function(data) {
            $('#commentBlock'+expressID).append(data);
            $("#getComment"+expressID).attr('value','');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please tell me how to pass `&` as text in URL. And how to replace it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second argument to pass a data hash. This way jQuery will take care of properly url encoding:

```
var data = { comment: comment, expressID: expressID };
$.get('../addons/comment.jsp', data, function(data) {
    $('#commentBlock'+expressID).append(data);
    $("#getComment"+expressID).attr('value','');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For any URL, Javascript notwithstanding, you must *encode* special characters that otherwise have special meaning:

```
// http://site.com/script.php?var1=string+with+%26+sign&var2=lol
//                                             ^^^

<?php
echo $_GET['var1']; // "string with & sign"
?>
```

However, in this case you should take advantage of jQuery to do this for you, by passing parameters to `$.get` as an object in the second argument.

Take a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).